# Find the value of $\lim \limits_{x \to \pi /3} \frac{(1-\cos6x)^{1/2}}{\sqrt 2 (\frac \pi3 - x)}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

> The question from my textbook requires us to find the value of the below limit:
>
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi /3} \frac{(1-\cos6x)^{1/2}}{\sqrt 2 (\pi/3 - x)}$$

On using the trigonometric identity $\cos2x = 1-2\sin^2x$, the above limit reduces to:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi /3} \frac{\lvert \sin3x \rvert}{\pi/3 - x}$$

On substituting $\frac \pi3 - x$ by $y$ the above limit becomes:

$$\lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{\lvert \sin3y \rvert}y$$

In this case, the left hand and right hand limits are unequal, being equal to $-3$ and $3$ respectively. Thus, $$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi /3} \frac{(1-\cos6x)^{1/2}}{\sqrt 2 (\pi/3 - x)} \text{ does not exist.}$$
But my textbook gives the answer as $3$. It was apparently because it considered $(1-\cos6x)^{1/2}$ as equal to $\sin 3x$ and not as equal to $\lvert \sin3x \rvert$. But since $x \to \pi/3$, shouldn't $(\sin^2 3x)^{1/2}$ equal $\lvert \sin3x \rvert$? Is my argument incorrect? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're right (but it's the other way around: 3 from the left and -3 from the right).

Comment: You are right, the limit does not exist

Comment: @StackTD For the LHL, $y \to 0^-$. So $\lvert \sin3y \rvert = - \sin3x$. The same argument goes for RHL.

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF Look at the original limit (some of the substitutions might need corrections): the numerator is always positive and the denominator is positive for $x \to \tfrac{\pi}{3}^-$ and negative for $x \to \tfrac{\pi}{3}^+$. This also agrees with the graph in one of the answers below.

Comment: @StackTD I still didn't get it. How do you get $LHL = 3$ and $RHL = -3$? Which of my substitutions is/are incorrect?

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF The substitutions are fine, but you have to be careful with the conclusions. It's subtle: because $y=\tfrac{\pi}{3}-x$, we have that $x \to \tfrac{\pi}{3}^+$ corresponds to $y \to 0^-$ and vice versa (so the LHL/RHL swap w.r.t. the variables $x$ and $y$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct; for example, see this graph: (the blue vertical line is at $\frac{\pi}{3}$)

[image: graph showing the function asked about near pi/3]

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $x=y+\pi/3$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi /3} \frac{(1-\cos6x)^{1/2}}{\sqrt 2 (\frac \pi3 - x)}=\lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos6y)^{1/2}}{-\sqrt 2 y }$$

then use standard limit

- $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to \frac12$

and observe that

- $y>0 \implies y=\sqrt {y^2}$
- $y<0 \implies y=-\sqrt {y^2}$

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your point. Maybe because I don't know how to evaluate the limit of a square root. Can you please give a little more explaination about using the standard limit you've mentioned?

Comment: Yes from here you can calculate the limits for $y\to0^+$ and for $y\to0^-$ and show that those are different.

Comment: I see. But how do I evaluate the limit of a function inside the square root?

Comment: let use $y=\sqrt {y^2}$ for $y>0$ and $y=-\sqrt {y^2}$ for $y<0$